# Display title and value in livecharts pie chart legend

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

We currently have a pie chart set up with a legend. The only way to see the actual values are by hovering over the pie chart and triggering the tooltip, or observing the number written on the chart. The latter isn't always displayed, specifically when the slice is too small, and tooltips are sometimes truncated. Both shown in my screenshot.

Therefore, the product owner would like to display the value next to the legend, as indicated by the red arrows in my screenshot.

I have tried creating a custom user control for the legend, however the data bound to this does not have access to the value, only the key (title).

Any tips?

[image: pie chart]